# Is it possible to create an OpenGL 4+ context within GTK / GtkGLExt?

Tags: opengl, gtk

To avoid unnecessary UI coding for a small 3D application, I would like to use GTK to create the necessary widgets. But I don't see a possibility to create a core 4+ context with GtkGLExt?

Update: 13 Apr. 15:

I recently found the following article [halting problem :: Using OpenGL with GTK+](https://www.bassi.io/articles/2015/02/17/using-opengl-with-gtk/) about this topic. Perhaps this could become useful for others.

However, the missing possibility to query and select the core-profile version is an indication that the usage is still limited to OpenGL 3.2 (Released in 2009).

Comment: It is necessary to patch _italic_gdk_gl_config_new_by_mode_common_italic_ by adding the version info with glXCreateContextAttribsARB (itself encapsulated by _italic_GdkGL_GLX_ARB_create_context_italic_). Reviewing the code, I doubt that this automatic context creation is a good idea. For Example, if I want an ES context on the desktop or my shader code works only on certain ogl versions. For a developer this could be a reason to switch to QT. Just make the wgl interface public if its to hard to write a usable wrapper for it.